# wso2 esb 611 read data from inbound endpoint FILE

Tags: csv, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

I was able to configure inbound endpoint FILE for CSV file(text/plain) and poll for a file and move it for a different folder, using vFS settings.

The problem is, how do I extract the contents of the CSV file and parse them?

Where do I find the data at run-time in WSO2 EI? Is there an XPath expression

Is there a mediator or proxy-service I should use to get the data as message?

Please explain the steps using tooling artifacts of WSO2.

Comment: https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-how-to-process-a-csv-file-using-the-smooks-mediator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I use the script mediator (even if smooks is recommended) like the following

```
<property description="Extract File name" expression="substring-before(get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME'),'.csv')" name="fileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    var csv = mc.getPayloadXML();     
    var lines = (csv + "").split("\n");

    for (var l = 1; l <= lines.length; l++) {
        cells = (lines[l] + "").split(";");
        // Perform your parsing
    }

    mc.setPayloadXML(payload);
    ]]>
</script>
```